# How would you simplify this ruby hash operation?

Tags: ruby

I need to create a hash which contains a number of parameters. If the value of the `max_id` parameter is nil though I want to remove the key from the hash:

```
params = { since_id: since_id, count: 50, max_id: max_id }
params.delete( :max_id ) unless max_id
```

The above code works fine but Ruby has so many nice hash and array operators that I wonder if there's an even cleaner way to write it (perhaps something using the splat operator).

Comment: I anticipated that too but delete is actually destructive so you don't need the bang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution looks good, although I'd do it the other way round:

```
params = { since_id: since_id, count: 50 }
params[:max_id] = max_id if max_id
```

Comment: Should that be `params[:max_id] = max_id if max_id` in this case, since you're inverting the approach?

Comment: Thanks. Though then again since OP mentioned `nil`, maybe it should be `... if max_id.nil?`. Have a +1 anyway

Comment: Yeah, it's ambiguous in the OP. That's why I just gave you +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

#### A specific key

If you just want to check for `:max_id` then your solution:

```
params.delete( :max_id ) unless max_id
```

is the cleanest one. Notice that if `max_id` is `false` then the key-value pair will be deleted, therefore I suggest you to use the below version instead:

```
params.delete( :max_id ) if max_id.nil?
```

#### A generic key

The cleanest way I can think of, using hash methods, to delete a key-value pair if the value is nil, is by using `Hash#reject!`:

```
params.reject! { |k, v| v.nil? }
```

This will reject all key-value pairs that has `nil` as value in the `params` hash.

There are other alternatives. All of the followings lines are equivalent (except for their returned value):

```
params.reject! { |k, v| v.nil? }
params.select! { |k, v| not v.nil? }
params.delete_if { |k, v| not v.nil? }
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be "value != nil" or similar? (value instead of key, and nil.is_nil? seems to raise an exception, whereas nil != nil works)

Comment: Apologies - I didn't word the question clearly enough. It's actually even simpler than this - I only want to remove one, specified parameter `max_id`

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, yeah I did a bunch of mistakes in the early versions of this answer. Now they should be all correct (or at least that's what my `irb` says).

Comment: @PeterNixey, I've edited my answer to include my old one and the correct one. Hope that helps :).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use reject:

```
params = params.reject {|key,value| value == nil }
```

Comment: `reject!` would be even shorter

Comment: Doh - completely forgot about that since I usually don't use the modifying versions. Thanks.